# How can I change these variables?

Tags: c, autotools

I have in my C code, which I based on [GNU hello](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/hello/hello-2.7.tar.gz), this

`printf (_("%s home page: <%s>\n"), PACKAGE_NAME, PACKAGE_URL);`

Now I want to change the package variables but I can't find where they are set. Do you know where I can change them? If I serach for the variables in my project I only find auto-generated files such as `config.h` etc.

The variables must come from somewhere, where is it?

The way I build my project is `./configure && make && sudo make install`

Comment: All-uppercase names are usually macros, not variables. Look for `#define PACKAGE_NAME`. They also could be coming from a makefile that puts `-DPACKAGE_NAME=whatever` in `CFLAGS`. And it's possible that the makefile is produce by an automated configuration tool.

Comment: @Barmar I have `#define PACKAGE_NAME` but in `config.log` and in config.h` but those are generated by automake aren't they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They come from the `configure` script:

```
# Identity of this package.
PACKAGE_NAME='GNU Hello'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='hello'
PACKAGE_VERSION='2.7'
PACKAGE_STRING='GNU Hello 2.7'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='bug-hello@gnu.org'
PACKAGE_URL='http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/'
```

`Makefile.in` contains:

```
PACKAGE_NAME = @PACKAGE_NAME@
PACKAGE_STRING = @PACKAGE_STRING@
PACKAGE_TARNAME = @PACKAGE_TARNAME@
PACKAGE_URL = @PACKAGE_URL@
PACKAGE_VERSION = @PACKAGE_VERSION@
```

and there's presumably something in the configure script that replaces all the `@VARNAME@` placeholders with the values of the variables.

I found these with:

```
grep -R PACKAGE_NAME .
```

while in the `hello-2.7` directory.

Comment: Thanks. I could change it in `configure` and achieve the change but I thought that `configure` was generated by `configure.ac` and that I shouldn't touch `configure`. Anyway it worked :-)

Comment: If `configure` were generated from something else, how could you run `./configure` to start the process?

Comment: @Barmar, in an Autotools build system, `configure` ***is*** generated by something else: `autoconf`.  But that is ordinarily the responsibility of the package maintainer.